# What statistical tools are available to remove bias from a dataset?

Tags: bias, ranking

Three managers report to me. They have done appraisal of staff under them giving them a percentage. I have to sign-off those ratings but I face two major issues:

1. The managers have a certain way of rating their staff. One manager consistently ranks his staff higher: most of his ratings are 87% - 95%. The other manager is more conservative and rates his staff more stringently i.e. 75% - 85%. I know from my personal experience that quality of staff under both the manager is homogeneous so it's not the factual representation.
2. Second issue is that managers have their likings and dislikings. They will rate certain staff more favorably than the others. I have historic ratings on their both liked and disliked staff (I know that their productivity is at par).

Without going into the discussion of how the appraisal system should work, could someone point out if there are any statistical tools available to detect and remove such bias from the data? (I remember vaguely that in college teachers used to apply some averaging technique to bring whole class's grade up depending upon who the highest scorer was. I am looking for something like that.)

Comment: What is the objective here? Beyond "removing bias"? What are you going to do with this data?

Comment: This process is used to rank the employees at the year end for the calculation of salary increments and bonus. For example employees in the range of 90% - 100% may receive the highest salary increments and bonuses and then there will be lower bands. So a certain manager may want to appease his staff more and thus rank all of them high. Or there might be a manager who is pissed off at his wife and may rank all his subordinates very poorly. So there might be a general bias in ranking of same staff from different appraisers. You see what I mean?

Comment: In principle, subtraction is the answer: corrected estimate = original estimate $-$ bias. In practice you just need to estimate bias. Tautological, no doubt.

Comment: If you know all the staff are the same then why give them different salary increments? You do not seem to trust the managers either with the absolute value of their ratings or even with their relative ratings.

Comment: @Henry I said homogeneous, not same

Comment: You seem to have said *"They will rate certain staff more favorably than the others... (I know that their productivity is at par)."*  You could, I suppose, compare each member of staff with that indiduidual's previous rating, though that too is possible to game.

Comment: Not sure how the history helps either: are consistently high ratings over the years evidence of an employee's consistently good performance or the boss's consistent favouritism?